# How to center fluid divs on same line?

Tags: css, dreamweaver

I'm using a fluid grid layout in Dreamweaver and I've got three divs on the same line. It looks good except I'd like to center all three divs on the page. Right now they are all shifted to the left, as that's obviously what they are being told to do. I just don't know how to tell them to be centered.

Help would be much appreciated!

It looks exactly like this at the moment (not my image):

[image]

```
#item1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 32.6007%;
    display: block;
}
#item2 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1.0989%;
    width: 32.6007%;
    display: block;
}
#item3 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1.0989%;
    width: 32.6007%;
    display: block;

#featuredholder {
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-left: 0;
width: 100%;
display: block;
}
```

EDIT:

Please take a look at this picture to see exactly what I'm working with. [image]

I need those divs centered and still be fluid.

Comment: Make sure you're checking the behaviour in a real browser, not Dreamweaver's Live View. It sucks.

Comment: Yeah, I almost never use live view.

Answer (score 1):

Hey now used to this css as like this

```
#wrapper{
margin:0 auto;
width:800px;
overflow:hidden;
}

#item1, #item2 , #item3 {
float:left;
width:30%;
 }
#item1{
margin-left:3%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you just need to add `margin: 0 auto;` to your wrapper.

```
#wrapper
{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

#item1 {
    float: left;
    width: 32.6007%;
}
#item2 {
    float: left;
    width: 32.6007%;
}
#item3 {
    float: left;
    width: 32.6007%;
}

span.clear /*clearfix*/
{
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Also you don't neet to declare `display: block;` on a div as it is a block level element by default. Remove the clears on the divs also, or this will break the float (this is what the `span.clear` is for after your three divs.)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/ZSYnW/

---

After your comment, you need to add in an extra div to wrap around the centered elements, set that div's margin to `0 auto` and restructure the rest of your HTML so that each block of two sits within another wrapper div :)

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/ZSYnW/1/

Comment: I appreciate your help! Unfortunately I could not seem to get this to work on my site despite your demo looking correct. Please take a look at this picture to see the site I am building and what needs to be centered. Please keep in mind that everything must remain fluid as well. http://i34.photobucket.com/albums/d146/camaero/layout22.jpg

Comment: Ok, you need to add another div and slightly restructure your markup to this: http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/ZSYnW/1/